# how to write maintainable UI Screen?

Tags: performance, flutter, dart

I want to write a readable and beautiful code so that anyone could understand it, as well as the code can be maintainable and scalable.

my code is that is it good or no?

[image]

Comment: Maybe take a look at [Atomic Design](http://atomicdesign.bradfrost.com/chapter-2/)?

Answer (score 1):

Create stateless widgets for smaller UI Components and compose bigger widgets or pages using these reusable UI widgets. for example :

Widgets Folder:

- custom_text.dart (a widget that gives me simple centered text).
- custom_button.dart (a custom reusable component).

Pages Folder:

- home_page.dart(a widget that includes a scaffold with custom_card
  inside)
- login_page.dart

here's an example

```
void main() => runApp(HomePage ());

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: SimpleTextWidget(), 
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is a small reusable component to be used in your other parent widget.

```
class SimpleTextWidget extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Center(
        child: Text('Hello'),);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain different files for keeping widgets and use the import statements for using them in any file. This will also make your code re-usable.

For writing a beautiful code, you must follow the indentation properly and you can also add useful comments to the code which will increase the readability of your code.